# How to install and use sigmajs in angular 7 and how to use startForceAtlas2 package of sigmajs

Tags: angular, sigma.js

How can I add sigmajs in angular 7 and how to use sigma js in angular 7.
Also, I want to use the startForceAtlas2 package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got your question

1. first install `npm install sigma --save`
2. in your componet `declare const sigma: any;`
3. in angular json import sigma script like
   `"node_modules/sigma/build/sigma.min.js",`
4. and call graph function of sigma js as example of sigmajs

and you will get a graph.

Comment: make sure you install version 1.2.1 in your package json for sigma. The new V2 alpha does not work with angular 8.

Comment: Yes @LukeKroon you are right, I have tried the above code. It has to be sigma 1.2.1 version.

Comment: And what about the adding the plugin part?

Answer (score 0):

To install sigma in angular, it is best to follow the documentation that they themselves offer: https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki

But getting into the nitty-gritty ... how the hell do we use force atlas or any of its plugins? Well, after giving myself many many head bumps I discovered the solution and it is so dumb that it works:

```
 <script src="./node_modules/sigma/build/plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/sigma/plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2/worker.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/sigma/plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2/supervisor.js"></script>
```

We will find them in node_modules after installing sigma.

Even so if we use import * from 'sigma' it won't work for us, we have to access sigma directly. In our component we use: `declare var sigma`

Once that is done we will use that variable as we did before:

```
 this.fundingNetwork = new sigma({
            renderer: {
                container: this.sigmaGraph.nativeElement,
                type: 'canvas'
            },
            settings: {
                // defaultHoverLabelBGColor: '#EEAB00',
                font: 'Poppins',
                defaultNodeBorderColor: '#58D68D'
            }
        });
```

And we can use the forceAtlas:

```
             this.fundingNetwork.startForceAtlas2({worker: true, barnesHutOptimize: false});
```

[image]